# Set finalnamedelim "and" instead of "&" in \fullcite (biblatex apa)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to change the finalnamedelim into "and" instead of "&" when using the \fullcite command (actually, when using any citing command). I am able to do that into the bibliography only with:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{% this puts "and" instead of "&" in the bibliography
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\space\bibstring{and}\space}%
}
```

How can I do that everywhere? Also, I need this to work with both a normal document and beamer. Thank you!

The full code is provided here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usebeamercolor{beaver}

\usepackage[style=apa,uniquename=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\AtBeginBibliography{% this puts "and" instead of "&" in the bibliography
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\space\bibstring{and}\space}%
}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Literature}

\fullcite{acemoglu2013political}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,uniquename=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clean solution! I had to use the first \DeclareDelimFormat only though, as the second was giving me an error. What does the second one do exactly? In any case, the first was enough to solve my problem. Thank you again!

Comment: @F.Ricca You may not be using the very newest version of `biblatex-apa`. `finalnamedelim:apa:family-given` is a special delimiter to solve the problems of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417648/35864. It is present from v7.6 onwards.