# Replacing Ampersand by and in Biblatex and APA

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am trying to get an equivalent for `\usepackage{apalike}` with bibtex, but with the ability to use `parencite` etc.

Therefore, I tried to use `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`, but every citation now contains ampersand instead of `and`.

For authoryear, defining `\finalnamedelim` works ([Use ampersand & in citations and bibliography in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68053/use-ampersand-in-citations-and-bibliography-in-biblatex)), like this:

```
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

and also for for the bibliography ([Replace 'and' with ampersand in bibliography and parenthetical citations using BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150461/replace-and-with-ampersand-in-bibliography-and-parenthetical-citations-using-b?rq=1)) with

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}
```

Unfortunately, for apa style I cannot make this work.

The only thing that works for apa is using `\DeclareDelimFormat` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590692/85628) like in this mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this also only works for the text itself, but not for the bibliography at the end. Additionally, this leads to more than 2 names being written completely (instead of being replaced by `et al.`).

Changing the declaration to

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bibliography,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

solves the problem with the 3 authors, but still, ampersand is used in the bibliography instead of `and`.

Additionally, references do not have the same format (`Alcocer, J. P. S. and Bergel, A. (2015). Tracking down performance variation against source code evolution. In Proceedings of the 11th Symposium on Dynamic Languages, DLS 2015, pages 129–139, New York, NY, USA. ACM.` is apalike and `Alcocer, J. P. S., & Bergel, A. (2015). Tracking down performance variation against source code evolution, In Proceedings of the 11th symposium on dynamic languages, Pittsburgh, PA, USA, ACM.` is APA).

Is there any solution, to let biblatex and biber behave exactly like `apalike`?

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that `apalike` is only, well ... *like* APA. The style is very old (it is one of the BibTeX base styles) and was inspired by/modelled after a now outdated version of APA style. [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa)'s `style=apa` on the other hand implements the current version of APA style (7th edition) as closely as possible with `biblatex`. So the results may indeed be very different.

Generally I recommend to use `biblatex-apa` only if you need real APA style. In particular `biblatex-apa` was not built for easy customisability. It was built to come as close as possible to APA style.

If you want something that is broadly "like APA" (i.e. an author-year style), I suggest you go for the `biblatex` standard style `authoryear` and modify it so you like the output. Yes, the output will be different from `apalike` (there simply is no `apalike` style for `biblatex`), but you can change the things you categorically do not like (a start for `biblatex` customisations is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), but you will find many, many questions about tons of different modifications on this site - and if you get stuck, you can just ask a new question) and maybe accept some of the things you do not feel strongly about.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: author-year citations and bibliography.]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I added some examples from `biblatex-examples.bib` to check th APA style.

Compile as `pdflatex` + `biber` + `pdflatex` + `pdflatex`.

[image: a]

This answer assumes you are using a current version of biblatex-apa (at least v9.0 from 2019-11-23) that implements 7th-edition APA style.

Check it adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{article}` and look the list of loaded files in the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
bibstyle=apa,
maxbibnames=99, %<<<<<
apamaxprtauth=99,%<<<<<
]{biblatex}


%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534084/161015 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
    {}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifcurrentname{groupauthor}\AND%
            \value{liststop}=2}
        {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
        {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}

%\usepackage{filecontents} % no needed <<<<<<<<<

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
@book{vizedom,
    title        = {The Rites of Passage},
    year         = 1960,
    author    = {Vizedom, Monika B. and Caffee, Gabrielle L. and Coulton, Paul},
    language     = {english},
    publisher    = {University of Chicago Press},
}
@online{baez,
    author       = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.} ,
    title        = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra {V}: 2-Groups},
    date         = {2004-10-27},
    version      = 3,
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    eprinttype   = {arxiv},
    eprint       = {math/0307200v3},
}

@report{chiu,
    author       = {Chiu, Willy W. and Chow, We Min and Chu, Fuman},
    title        = {A Hybrid Hierarchical Model of a {Multiple Virtual Storage}
        ({MVS}) Operating System},
    type         = {resreport},
    institution  = {IBM},
    date         = 1978,
    number       = {RC-6947},
    langid       = {english},
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    Some text   \autocite{A01}
    
    \autocite{vizedom}
    
    \cite{chiu}
    
    \textcite{baez}
    
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```