# Biblatex APA-7 Modification

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

My university has the requirement to not have a final comma before the ampersand of the final author.

Here's the full cite:

> Blinowski, G., Anna, O., & Adam, P. (2022). Monolithic vs. Microservice Architecture: A Performance and
> Scalability Evaluation. IEEE Access, 10, 20357–20374. https://doi.org/10.1109/ACCESS.2022.3152803

The comma in between "Anna, O., (<-- this here)" and "& Adam, P." needs to be removed. How can I adjust this?

I'm using `biblatex` as follows:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

I was able to get rid of this comma. But, I've noticed in Overleaf, that this only works with TexLive 2021 or below. If I switch to 2022, `biblatex` automatically adds a comma there.  `\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{;}` don't replace the comma but adds a semicolon after the comma... So this is super strange to me. Is anyone aware of this "bug"?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,hyperref,style=apa,citestyle=apa,cites]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{ref,
    author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title = {The LaTeX Companion},
    year = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}


\AtBeginDocument{% this is solving it
    \renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] A cite: \cite{ref}. 
\item[] A parencite: \parencite{ref}.
\item[] A textcite: \textcite{ref}.
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the comma in this position is not logically a `\finalandcomma`. See the discussions in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/48 and [biblatex-apa is missing commas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417648/35864) (and the links there). You can find the current implementation of the comma explained in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/144 (see also https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/191).

To get rid of the comma we need to redefine `\apablx@ifrevnameappcomma`. (But then we still need to reset `\finalandcomma` so *it* doesn't kick in.)

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\apablx@ifrevnameappcomma}{\@secondoftwo}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,companion,aksin,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F. & Samarin, A. (1994).]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly in Overleaf with TexLive 2022 and lualatex. Locally, it gives me the error "Command \apablx@ifrevnameappcomma undefined." Do you also have an idea here?

Comment: @Markus Presumably your local installation is outdated. This answer assumes a fairly recent `biblatex-apa`. Update your local system (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864).