How to remove Oxford comma in bibliography?
I'm trying to remove the comma before & in the citation list.
This is what it looks like:

Carnazzo, V., Redi, S., Basile, V., Natali, P., Gulli, F., Equitani, F., Marino, M.,
& Basile, U. (2024) Calprotectin: Two sides of the same coin. Rheumatology, 63 (1), 26–33. doi: 10.1093/rheumatology/kead405.

This is what I want it to look like:

Carnazzo, V., Redi, S., Basile, V., Natali, P., Gulli, F., Equitani, F., Marino, M.
& Basile, U. (2024) Calprotectin: Two sides of the same coin. Rheumatology, 63 (1), 26–33. doi: 10.1093/rheumatology/kead405.

This is what my code looks like:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, maxbibnames=99, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{%
    #1 \addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
    \mkbibacro{#1}\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \lowercase{doi}\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @article{Car:24,
        author={Carnazzo, V. and Redi, S. and Basile, V. and Natali, P. and Gulli, F. and Equitani, F. and Marino, M. and Basile, U.},
        title={Calprotectin: two sides of the same coin.},
        journal={Rheumatology},
        volume={63},
        number={1},
        pages={26-33},
        year={2024},
        doi={10.1093/rheumatology/kead405}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Car:24}
\printbibliography[title={Reference List},heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}

The entry in the bibliography file looks like this:
@article{Car:24,
    author={Carnazzo, V. and Redi, S. and Basile, V. and Natali, P. and Gulli, F. and Equitani, F. and Marino, M. and Basile, U.},
    title={Calprotectin: two sides of the same coin.},
    journal={Rheumatology},
    volume={63},
    number={1},
    pages={26-33},
    year={2024},
    doi={10.1093/rheumatology/kead405}
}

I've tried turning various things 'British' and \DefineBibliographyExtra, however, nothing I've done has removed this comma.
Bonus question (although at this point, I've just come to live with it), do you know how to make the punctuation after the journal a full stop rather than a comma? Ideally, my citation would look like:

Carnazzo, V., Redi, S., Basile, V., Natali, P., Gulli, F., Equitani, F., Marino, M.
& Basile, U. (2024) Calprotectin: Two sides of the same coin. Rheumatology. 63 (1), 26–33. doi: 10.1093/rheumatology/kead405.


Part of your problems (no comma after last author before and) can be solved by this answer. However, since you redefine \newunitpunct, it messes with the internal formatting of the apa style, which makes it even harder to adapt. Besides the apa style being really complex and therefor not easy to manipulate, your desired change of , to . after the journal title is considered in general to be bad practice and should be avoided if possible.

@dsacre Thank you! I managed to fix both of my issues with that post. The full stop after the journal title is my university's recommended citation format. However, I actually think it looked better beforehand, so now I need to decide whether to keep the full stop or go back to the comma.

Glad to hear the other post helped. Could you please post your revised code as an answer, so that others can see that - and how - the issue was solved.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670888/35864 about the comma.

I managed to fix my code using the answer that @dsacre shared, however, for some reason this didn't actually fix the issue in my MWE. But I managed to fix my MWE with the link that @moewe shared, and this also works in my main document.
Here was my solution:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, maxbibnames=99, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{%
    #1 \addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
    \mkbibacro{#1}\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \lowercase{doi}\addcolon\space
    \ifhyperref
    {\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

%%%%%%%% Get rid of the oxford comma
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\apablx@ifrevnameappcomma}{\@secondoftwo}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}%
}

%%%%%%%%%% Change comma after journal to a full stop
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  }

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @article{Car:24,
        author={Carnazzo, V. and Redi, S. and Basile, V. and Natali, P. and Gulli, F. and Equitani, F. and Marino, M. and Basile, U.},
        title={Calprotectin: two sides of the same coin.},
        journal={Rheumatology},
        volume={63},
        number={1},
        pages={26-33},
        year={2024},
        doi={10.1093/rheumatology/kead405}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Car:24}
\printbibliography[title={Reference List},heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}

